# Categorize data by time periods

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am looking for a SQL statement to select all rows from the table with time periods like Today, Yesterday..etc. The table holds one `datetime` column.

Here result set should automatically populate results with pretty date (Today, yesterday,.. Last month, Older)and number of records on the periods,

Today -- 10

Yesterday -- 35

[image]

Comment: Remove the `where` clause and select all rows.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to *define* the time periods, then use `case`.  You don't really define the exact definitions, but something like this:

```
select (case when col >= convert(date, getdate()) then 'Today'
             when col >= dateadd(day, -1, convert(date, getdate())) then 'Yesterday'
             when col >= dateadd(day, -6, convert(date, getdate())) then datename(weekday, col)
             when col >= dateadd(day, -13, convert(date, getdate())) then 'Last Week'
             when col >= dateadd(day, -20, convert(date, getdate())) then 'Two Weeks Ago'
             when col >= dateadd(day, -27, convert(date, getdate())) then 'Thre Weeks Ago'
             else 'Older'
        end)
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=99b56034fe33680befb7b3bf80bdfff4) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'then'.